# Ionic 2 build with background image

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Good day,

I built a mobile app using Ionic version 2, when I run ionic serve, I get to see the background image and logo of my application on the login page. On building the app I don't get to see the background image and/or logo.

```
<ion-row center style="margin-top: 50%;">
    <ion-col width-20></ion-col>
    <ion-col width-60>
        <img src="images/DD_logo.png" style="width:100%" class="thumbnail"/>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-20></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

this is the part where a logo is to appear this is from *~/app/pages/profile/profile.html*

Comment: how are you providing background image to your app. Share you code please.

Comment: Atula, Thanks for the response. Please, find added the snippet of the code in question.

Comment: I don't see any snippet @cookies.

Comment: <ion-row center style="margin-top: 50%;">
    <ion-col width-20></ion-col>
    <ion-col width-60>
        <img src="images/DD_logo.png" style="width:100%" class="thumbnail"/>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-20></ion-col>
</ion-row>

Comment: Your code is working smoothly on my side. Problem is something else.

Answer (score 0):

ok lets give it a try. It is the basic method for background image in `ionic` as well as in `ionic 2`.
*css*

```
#Image {
background: url(images/DD_logo.png) no-repeat center;
width:100%;
}
```

*html*

```
 <img id="Image" src="" class="thumbnail"/>
```

Comment: Okay noted. The images display on ionic serve, but when compiled for the device (ie when an apk is created), the image disappears / never displays.

Comment: Also provide me .thumnail

Comment: yes I also tried the above code. My guess is that the images are not being copied into the build directory thereby causing these issues.

Comment: try if an external image loads up or not. give url of external image